# Finding solutions to the diophantine equation $xy(x+y) = n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I initially wanted to prove that there are no integer solutions for the equation $xy(x+y) = 4$, but I got intrigued by the general case as I noticed that there tends to be solutions when $n$ is in the form $2^a$. For example, $4 \times 4 \times(4+4)=2^7$. I have tried using the quadratic formula to solve for x in terms of y to reduce the original equation to a single-variable equation, but it gets far too messy:

$$ x = \frac{-y^2 \pm \sqrt{y^4 + 4ny}}{2y} \\ 
(-\frac{y^2}{2} \pm \frac1{2}\sqrt{y^4+4ny})(\frac{y}{2} \pm \frac1{2y}\sqrt{y^4+4ny})=n
$$

I also see that $xy(x+y)$ is a multiplication of three almost independent (since addition makes factoring hard) terms, so we would have to somehow split numbers into 3 divisions.

Are there any concise special cases for n? And how would you approach disproving the existence of solutions given a specific n?

Comment: Degree is already $3$ ; at least homogenous polynomial :) ; could be hard to classify numbers that can be represented that way.

Comment: Simple observations: Odd $n$ can never work. $2p^a$ works iff  $a\equiv 0\pmod 3$ or $p=3$, $a\equiv 1\pmod 3$. (In particular $2^a$ works iff $a\equiv 1\pmod 3$.

Comment: On the last question: "And how would you approach disproving the existence of solutions given a specific n?" - if the $n$ is not too big (like $n=4$), we can just test all possible divisors of $n$ for $x$ and then solve for $y$ to see if it's an integer.

Comment: See [OEIS sequence A088915](https://oeis.org/A088915).

Answer (score 4):

This may help:
If $xy(x+y)=n$ then $(x+y)^3=3n+x^3+y^3$ which means $3n=(x+y)^3-x^3-y^3$ which shows that $3n$ is of a special kind, since we know that not every number is represented with $3$ cubes (with mixed sign).

Answer (score -1):

Above equation shown below

$xy(x+y) = n$  ------$(1)$

Equation $(1)$ has parametric solution & given below:

$x= k(k+1)(3k^2-4k-2)$

$y=5(-k)^3(k+1)$

$n=10k^5(k+1)^5(3k^2-4k-2)$

For $k=2$, we get:

$(x,y,n)=[(12),(-120),(155520)]$

Comment: When I plug $k=2$ into your formula I get $n=1920$, which does not satisfy the original equation.  Certainly there are other solutions, so this approach will not prove we cannot make a particular $n$

Comment: @Ross Millikan. Note that formula for OP equation has been corrected-Sam